# A word to describe a person who can change his voice at will

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Somebody who has the gift or has learned the ability to speak in a different accent other than his native accent, such as a person having a native British accent, but is able to speak in a Chinese accent, if he or she so wishes to.

Comment: Ventriloquists demonstrate this trait.

Answer (score 5):

A ***mimic***.

[From MW dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mimic):

> Simple Definition of **mimic** : a person who copies the behavior or
>   speech of other people
>
> **Example** of mimic in a sentence:
>   a gifted mimic who can do a terrific imitation of anyone's voice

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is IMPERSONATOR.  At least that's the word I was trying to remember..  Just one of those things stuck at the tip of my tounge.. Drove me to google once more..  ..... Or IMPERSONATION ..Example:  At Ten and two my friends and I do great British impersonations..

Comment: An impersonator mimics a ***specific*** person. I think OP is asking just about speaking in a different accent without trying to sound as if they were a specific person.

Answer (score 1):

An ***[imitator](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/imitator)*** has that ability:

> - a person ***who imitates another's voice*** and mannerisms for comic effect that comedian is a hilarious imitator of a surprising array of current celebrities.

(M-W)